# Insert endline after all semicolons except the two in for loop

Tags: java, string, char

I am writing a program which should insert an endline after every `; { }`. But there is a situation where my code inserts an endline after every `;`. The whole expression is in the string variable.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { //any code}
```

It will convert it to

```
for(int i=0;
  i<10;
  i++) {
   //any code
}
```

I want the output to be like:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   //anything  
}
```

My code is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {

    if (sb.charAt(i) == ';' ) {
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '}') {
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '{') {
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look ahead. You need ';' **and** '{' symbols in one line. Your if-statements work as **or** operation. For example, set some flag if there is ';' in line, and then insert newline character if you find '{' **and** flag is set.

Comment: there maybe ; and { in one line and may b not is there a genetic solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check if the semicolon comes between paranthesis or not. If it is, then don't add a newline (`\n`), if it's not, then add it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
boolean paranthesis = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '('){
        paranthesis = true;
    }
    else if (sb.charAt(i) == ')'){
        paranthesis = false;
    }
    else if (sb.charAt(i) == ';' ) {
        if (!paranthesis)
            sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
    else if (sb.charAt(i) == '}') {
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
    else if (sb.charAt(i) == '{') {
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\n');
    }
}
```

See this implementation [live here](http://ideone.com/TNPd03).